# How can I send a integer from my Java file to my XML folder? (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, xml, integer, load

I have an int called playerCount in my MainActivity Java file and would like to import it to my XML file, How would I go about doing that?

When I loaded an Java Method I wrote

```
android:onClick="playSound"
```

And then,

```
public void playSound(View view) {  
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.sound);  
    mediaPlayer.start();     
}
```

What I'm trying to say is how do I load an number stored in an integer in an java file to xml? For example

```
android:text="(the integer would go int here)"
```

I'm using Arduino Studio messing around and trying to make my first app, I have some experience with Java from before.

Thanks

Comment: you cannot load the number to the xml file. you would need to use setText() method to set the text

Comment: So I cant take input use Java IFs and logic and then transfer it to the XML? I guess I have to rethink my idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually want to put that integer inside your XML file.

Your XML file contains views right? Like `<TextView></TextView>`. These should also contain an id like `android:id="@+id/myTextView"`

You can give these views certain values you want with methods like `setText();`
First find the view by the ID and then set the integer as a text value for the `TextView`.

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
textView.setText(playerCount+"");
```